# Why SSO is not working even after setting cookie in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, cookies, webview, single-sign-on, wkwebview

I have 2 applications, both app uses the WKWebview for SSO login. Both apps are working fine individually.

Now let's take this below scenario.

Suppose i logged in one app, retrieved the WKWebview cookie from this app & set this cookie info in WKWebview of 2nd app.My expectation is SSO should work in 2nd app but it isn't working.

Below is the code i am using for Retrieving cookie from WKwebview after login from 1st app

> extension WKWebView {
>
> ```
> @available(iOS 11.0, *)
> private var httpCookieStore: WKHTTPCookieStore  {
>     return WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
> }
>
> func getCookies(for domain: String? = nil, completion: @escaping ([String : Any])->())  {
>     var cookieDict = [String : AnyObject]()
>     if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
>         httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { (cookies) in
>             for cookie in cookies {
>                 print("cookie iterator started")
>                 print("cookie=======\(cookie)")
>
>                 if let domain = domain {
>                     if cookie.domain.contains(domain) {
>                         cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
>                     }
>                 } else {
>                     cookieDict[cookie.name] = cookie.properties as AnyObject?
>                 }
>             }
>             completion(cookieDict)
>         }
>     } else {
>         // Fallback on earlier versions
>     }
> } }
> ```

Below is the code i am using for setting cookie in WKwebview of 2nd app

```
 let cookie= HTTPCookie(properties: [
              .domain: "dev.mycompany.net",
              .path: "/",
              .name: "PF",
              .value: "327y48234g2hgdhjwedguyw23oSYVbVLwf9",
              .secure: "TRUE",
             .version: 1,
             .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: (562225018+1000000))
              ])!

HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
```

Comment: this is logged in cookie "327y48234g2hgdhjwedguyw23oSYVbVLwf9" right ? ask your server developer this cookie should be valid after signed in by user

Comment: debug your cookie through Safari developer portal your latest cookie should be there.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are doing wrong in 2nd app **Wkwebview** has their own cookie storage. but you are supposing this will set the cookie in **Wkwebview** `HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)` .To set up cookie in 2nd app **Wkwebview** you should set up your Logged in Cookie in **httpcookiestore** of **Wkwebview**.

```
self.webview.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie("your http cookie here", completionHandler: {
```

// do whatever you want here. now cookie is set in wkwebview

```
})
```

Use this method to make cookie.

```
let newcookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
        .domain: "your domain",
        .path: "/",
        .name: "name",
        .value: "value",
        .secure: "FALSE",
        .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)
        ])!
```

Comment: Thanks @shauket for quick reply. Yes i already tried this but still it wasn't working

Comment: are you sure your new cookie is Logged in Cookie ? i am 100% sure if it looged in cookie then safari web browser should show and your server recognize it. but if you are saying cookie is not setting up then is problem in your side.. otheriwse it seems to be your cookie is not valid

Comment: FYI which ios version are you checking ? Also your cookie is setup for this domain "dev.mycompany.net" so your server only recognize this domain

Comment: I am using WKWebview not  safari web browser. Yes i am retrieving cookie after login and off course it's valid because SSO is working in 1st app using this cookie info.I am checking this in Simulator with iOS version 11.4.

One thing i noticed above cookie info is changing when i am trying to login in 2nd app.

"PF": {
    Created = 562489153;
    Discard = TRUE;
    Domain = "dev.mycompany.net";
    Name = PF;
    Path = "/";
    Secure = TRUE;
    Value = JYFs8Xsa5L4jG92WV1VGSM;
    Version = 1;
}

Comment: Then please consult with your server guy may be there are some other constraint also require for login. WKHTTPCookieStoreObserver implement this observer may this help